# How to start a file download in vaadin without button?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I know that it is really easy to create a `FileDownloader` and call extend with a `Button`. But how do I start a download without the `Button`? 
In my specific situation right now I have a `ComboBox` and the file I'd like to send to the user is generated after changing its value, based on the input. The file should be sent immediately without waiting for another click. Is that easily possible?

Thanks
raffael

Comment: The problem with the hidden button is, that this does not work on devices with iOS. I'd rather use MenuBar and MenuItem, but this is not yet supported by Vaadin - see [Github issue #4057](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/4057). And the suggested workaround when using MenuBar and MenuItem would result in using hidden buttons ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Actually two. 
The first one uses the deprecated method [Page.open()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#open%28com.vaadin.server.Resource,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

```
public class DownloadComponent extends CustomComponent implements ValueChangeListener {
private ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

public DownloadComponent() {
    cb.addValueChangeListener(this);
    cb.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
    cb.setImmediate(true);
    cb.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    setCompositionRoot(cb);
}

@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String val = (String) event.getProperty().getValue();
    FileResource res = new FileResource(new File(val));
    Page.getCurrent().open(res, null, false);
}
}
```

The javadoc [here](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/LegacyWindow.html#open%28com.vaadin.server.Resource,%20java.lang.String%29) mentions some memory and security problems as reason for marking it deprecated

---

In the second I try to go around this deprecated method by registering the resource in the DownloadComponent. I'd be glad if a vaadin expert comments this solution.

```
public class DownloadComponent extends CustomComponent implements ValueChangeListener {
private ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
private static final String MYKEY = "download";

public DownloadComponent() {
    cb.addValueChangeListener(this);
    cb.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
    cb.setImmediate(true);
    cb.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    setCompositionRoot(cb);
}

@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String val = (String) event.getProperty().getValue();
    FileResource res = new FileResource(new File(val));
    setResource(MYKEY, res);
    ResourceReference rr = ResourceReference.create(res, this, MYKEY);
    Page.getCurrent().open(rr.getURL(), null);
}
}
```

Note: I do not really allow the user to open all my files on the server and you should **not** do that either. It is just for demonstration.

Comment: Do these solutions open the file in a new tab or a new popup ?

Comment: you can control the behaviour by setting the windowName parameter in Page.open() see: https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.7/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't open the "Save as" File browser

Comment: it is possible that the browser blocks the popup

Comment: How do you define where does the file gets downloaded to?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my work-around. It works like a charm for me. Hope it will help you.

1. Create a button and hide it by Css (NOT by code: button.setInvisible(false))

   ```
   final Button downloadInvisibleButton = new Button();
   downloadInvisibleButton.setId("DownloadButtonId");
   downloadInvisibleButton.addStyleName("InvisibleButton");
   ```

   In your theme, add this rule to hide the `downloadInvisibleButton`:

   ```
   .InvisibleButton {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
2. When the user clicks on menuItem: extend the `fileDownloader` to the `downloadInvisibleButton`, then simulate the click on the `downloadInvisibleButton` by JavaScript.

   ```
   menuBar.addItem("Download", new MenuBar.Command() {
     @Override
     public void menuSelected(MenuBar.MenuItem selectedItem) {
       FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(...);
       fileDownloader.extend(downloadInvisibleButton);
       //Simulate the click on downloadInvisibleButton by JavaScript
       Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript()
          .execute("document.getElementById('DownloadButtonId').click();");
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: imho this is not working cause every click on the same item will add an extension for the invisibleButton and therefore it will fire one dowload first time, but two download the second...and so on..

Comment: Lorenzo: Before calling extend(), you need to remove all old extensions of the button.