# Getting the URL from a Vaadin ResourceReference the correct way

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I am trying to download a zip file using Vaadin without the user having to click a button. This can be done using `Page.open()`. My problem is that I am setting the StreamResource to download this way:

```
    final StreamResource myResource = createResource();
    setResource("dl", myResource);
    getUI().getConnectorTracker().setDiffState(this, null);
    final ResourceReference ref = ResourceReference.create(myResource, UI.getCurrent(), "dl");
```

Unfortunately `ref.getURL()` is null, which does not allow me to open the file. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400017/how-to-start-a-file-download-in-vaadin-without-button) is the approach I was trying to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure this is intended to work in vaadin 7. A NULL URL is usually meaning that the component is not yet bound to the "output" dom tree.
Perhaps it would be better to use request handlers??  https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.requesthandler.html

Comment: Where are you using this code? Inside of a `Copmonent`? Why the `FileDownloader` and setDiffState(this, null)? Further you should create the `ResourceReference with the same Component us are setting the Resource.

Comment: @raffael Sorry about the 'FileDownloader' it was in there from a previous version. I am using it inside a Component.

Comment: What version of vaadin are you using. In vaadin 7.2.2 (and probably all vaadin 7 version) I don't see how getURL() should return null. But the way you are creating a `ResourceReference`, it will return a false url. You should use the current `Component` object (most likly just "this") instead of UI.getCurrent().